# Read a string from a file, skip the rest of the line after a certain character

Tags: java, string, file, java.util.scanner

I am currently learning how to use Java. I am trying to read a file using the scanner class and I want to read the file but ignore the rest of the line after a certain character eg #. say the file reads

```
 P5 #ignorethis
 #ignorealso
 123 123 123 #thisneedstogo
 355 255 345 #alsothis goes
```

the file I am trying to read has comments after the symbol '#' and they last till the end of the line. I want to read the strings of the file, whilst ignoring '#' and everything after that.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Which part are you having problems with? Reading the lines or skipping after the specified character? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Read the file one line at a time and then consider using the [`replaceAll(String string)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method which takes a regular expression on the line you have just read. You would then use something like so: `#.*$` to replace the `#` character and whatever follows till the end of the string with an empty string.

You could then write the string back to some other file or console once that you are done.

Answer (score 1):

From the Scanner's class doc:

> A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern,
>   which by default matches whitespace.

You can do it using useDelimiter method and regular expressions

As an example:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = " P5 #ignorethis\n" +
            " #ignorealso\n" +
            " 123 123 123 #thisneedstogo\n" +
            " 355 255 345 #alsothis goes";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s).useDelimiter("#.*");
    while (scanner.hasNext()){
        System.out.print(scanner.next());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(new File("input.txt")));

       while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
           String str = scanner.nextLine();
           System.out.println(str.substring(0, str.indexOf("#")));
       }
       scanner.close;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also read whole line, and then use just one part of it, like this:

```
public void readFile(File file){
    String line = "";
    try{
    scanner = new Scanner(file);
    }catch (FileNotFoundException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
    while (scanner.hasNext()){
        line = scanner.nextLine();
        String parts[] = line.split("#");
        System.out.println(parts[0]);
    }
}
```

This method read new line to String, split a String in a place of "#", and use part before "#" occurrence. Here is output:

> P5
>
> 123 123 123
>   355 255 345

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("name_file"))) {
String line;
String result = "";

      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

              if(line.trim().startsWith("#"))
                   {
                     System.out.println("next line");
                   }
               else
                   {
                       int index = line.indexOf("#"); 
                       if(index != -1){                        
                       String split = line.substring(0,index);
                       String[] sLine = line.trim().split("\t");
                       result = result + " " +split;
                       }
               else
                    {

                       String[] sLine = line.trim().split("\t");
                       result = result + " " +line;
                     }

                   }

            }

          br.close();
          System.out.println(result);
```